# How To Convert a nested for Loop to Recursive

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, recursion

Can anyone help me converting this for loop into a recursive method:
So far I added these two methods but I still want to change the second loop.
Thank you in advance.

```
       public void makeDesign1() {
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // For loop is the one creating the rows
    {
        for (x = 4; x > i; x--) // Nested loop is the one creating the columns 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

}

public static int makeDesign1Recur(int i) {

    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    System.out.print("*");
    return (makeDesign1Recur(i-1));
}
// How to convert this second loop recursive?
public static void makeDesignRow(int i){
   for ( int x = i; x>=0; x--){
       makeDesign1Recur(x);
       System.out.println("");
   }


}
```

Comment: Your inner `for` loop won't even execute, I think, because `i` has a max value of 4.  You might want to add a problem statement to your question.  There is nothing wrong with expressing a problem using two `for` loops, by the way.

Comment: Please show your attempt and highlight where you are having problems. We won't do your work for you, but will help you if you show what you have done.

Comment: it does work. It prints something like:

Comment: something like this, a few starts on screen: ****
***
**
*

Comment: I need to convert the same for loop into recursive method.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, so far I have this:
    public static int makeDesign1Recur(int i){
        
        if (i<5){
            return 0;
        }
                            
        
            return(i);
    }

Comment: to make `makeDesign1Recur` recursive, you need to call `makeDesign1Recur` from `makeDesign1Recur`

Comment: Thanks Scary, something like this:  return(makeDesign1Recur(i-1));

Comment: wow - yes, and then `makeDesign1Recur` needs to print something when it is *within* bounds. Also think how you will call this from `main`

Comment: What about the nested loop how can I add it as well?

Comment: When the recursive method is within bound you can do what ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the first step as redefining `makeDesign1()` correctly.  We want to pass in a size for our drawing.  We also want to change the bounds slightly so a size of 1 draws one star, instead of none like the original:

```
public static void makeDesign(int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // For loop is the one creating the rows
    {
        for (int x = n; x > i; x--) // Nested loop is the one creating the columns 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

The next step is to get both loops to count down to 1 to simplify the recursion when the time comes:

```
public static void makeDesign(int n) 
{
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) // For loop is the one creating the rows
    {
        for (int x = i; x > 0; x--) // Nested loop is the one creating the columns 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Now we can simply convert each loop into it's own recursive function, one calling the other:

```
public static void makeDesign(int n) 
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        makeDesignRow(n);
        makeDesign(n - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void makeDesignRow(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
        makeDesignRow(x - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

Passing `makeDesign()` an argument of 10, we get:

```
> java Main
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

>
```